# Laravel multiple whereIn array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I was wondering if there is a way to use whereIn with an array of arrays, 
something like the where with array

```
User::where(['user_id' => $currentUser, 'group_id' => $currentGroup]);
```

so i'm looking for this:

```
User::whereIn(['group' => $availableGroups, 'session' => $currentSessions]).
```

which should be equivalent to using the whereIn clause twice.

I was thinking of solving this like:

```
foreach (query as $key => $value)
   $userQuery->whereIn($key, $value);
```

I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that's not possible. You have to use `whereIn()` multiple times (or in a loop).

There's no logic that would handle such a parameter correctly:

```
public function whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    $type = $not ? 'NotIn' : 'In';

    // ... irrelevant code omitted ...

    $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'column', 'values', 'boolean');

    $this->addBinding($values, 'where');

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "no logic that would handle ..."

Comment: The code I posted is from the framework core. If an array of arrays was supported, the method would contain logic to handle that. Probably call `whereIn` for every subarray... I added this code to prove my statement.